# git commit -m "hogehoge" とした後で、editor を開かない方法が知りたい

Tags: git

そのまま保存してeditor を閉じるので editor は開きたくありません。
なにかオプションとかあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--no-edit` オプションをつけると良いと思います。

```
git commit -m "hogehoge" --no-edit
```

毎回つけるのが面倒なら、エイリアスを設定してください。たとえば以下のようにできます。

```
[alias]
    commit-m = commit --no-edit -m
```

(ところで私の環境では `-m <message>` オプションがあるときにはエディタが立ち上がらないので、何か他の設定がついていないか `git config --list` で確認してみてください。 `man git-commit` の `-e, --edit` オプションの説明にも、`-m` オプションがあるときは通常、渡された文字列を変更せずにそのままコミットログのメッセージとして使うと書いてあります。)